# How to join two tables while only selecting the highest day of each month from one table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have two tables. One with metadata, one with billing data. I need to join those effiently in order to assign metadata to costs.

Table 1 (metadata) looks like this:

```
year    month   day id          label1     label2
2021    06      04  892221805   foo        aaa
2021    06      30  892221805   bar        aaa     
2021    06      04  594083437   baz        aaa
2021    06      04  552604244   baz        bbb
```

Table 2 (billing data) looks like this:

```
year    month   id          cost
2021    06      892221805   1.00 $
2021    06      892221805   1.00 $    
2021    06      594083437   1.00 $
2021    06      552604244   1.00 $
```

For each combination of year, month, id in Table 2, there is an corresponding ID in Table 1.

For each year, month, id in T2, i need label1, label2 from the row in T1 which matches year, month, id, and has the highest date (in that month), so that the result may look like this:

```
year    month   id          cost   label1 label2
2021    06      892221805   1.00 $ bar    aaa
2021    06      892221805   1.00 $ bar    aaa
2021    06      594083437   1.00 $ baz    aaa
2021    06      552604244   1.00 $ baz    bbb
```

I.e. the first row of T1 is not used, as the second row has labels with a newer date in that month.

I am using Atheana on Amazon Webservices, which should be Presto compatible, I think.

How do I select this correctly? Preferably, in a way that can be used as a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to get to the last row in a month:

```
select t2.*, t1.label1, t1.label2
from table2 t2 left join
     (select t1.*
             row_number() over (partition by year, month, id order by day desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.year = t2.year and
        t1.month = t2.month and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: `and seqnum ..`